# Is it possible to write a recursive method in java where all items in a list is replaced by the last element?(without using loops)

Tags: java, list, generics, recursion

for example, if a list has elements (a,b,c,d,e), after calling the method it should have (e,e,e,e,e)

Let's say the there is a generic method:

```
public static <T> void duplicateLast(List<T> list){}
```

Is it possible to write a recursive method where all items in a list is replaced by the last element without using any loops whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely - the approach is as follows:

- The recursive element always looks at the current node in the list (see the note below for signature changes).
- If the current element is the last one in the list, return its value
- Otherwise, make a recursive call, assign the value that you get from it to your own element, and return the same value.

Note: You would need to change the signature of your recursive method to return `T`, and use a list iterator instead of a list, so that your method works equally well with linked lists and array lists.

Here is how you can implement it:

```
static <T> T recursiveLast(ListIterator<T> iter) {
    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        // It is invalid to call recursiveLast on an empty list
        return null;
    }
    T val = iter.next();
    // Base case is when hasNext() returns false
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
        val = recursiveLast(iter);
    }
    iter.previous();
    iter.set(val);
    return val;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/hFnfRz)

Answer (score 0):

First: you check if your list has more than one element. If not, stop here.

Second: you replace the first element by the last one.

Third: you do a recursive call on your function passing a sublist without the first element in parameter.

That's all.

I let you code that in Java :-)